# Save search functionality in the SharePoint 2010 Page

Tags: search, search-scope

I have an OOTB Advance Search and Results Page in SP 2010. I like to add a link for "Save Search" to enable users to save their search criteria. When user clicks on search and check the save search results check box the search results page URL (including the query string) should be updated in a custom list with metadata as SavedSearchName, URL and Timestamp.

I would then use a ListView webpart to query the above list to view the Saved Searches on the Advanaced Search Page with Name as text and hyperlink as URL to SearchResults with query string included.

How should I achieve this functionality. Is it possible to do in an OOTB advanced search Page?

Please suggest.

Cheers,

Amit

Answer (score 1):

The full solution can't be OOTB. All you can read right here are ideas, not definitive solutions.. :)

Why don't you use some javascript and/or event handler to catch the box-checking then by code, saving the data you want into the right list ?
The button/checkbox would be added to the page by customizing the masterpage / page layout ?